# upgrading from spring security 3.2.7.RELEASE to 4.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to upgrade my Spring Boot application with a Spring Security from version 3.2.7.RELEASE to recently released 4.0.0.RELEASE version and now it stopped working with "Access Denied" exception.

Before, I have successfully used Spring Security oAuth2 version 2.0.7.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.2.7.RELEASE

What can be a reason of it ?

Comment: Have you followed the [migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#m3to4)?  A number of things have changed from 3.x to 4.x so do make sure to follow the migration steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use Spring Security 4.0.0 with Spring Security OAuth2, it currently is not officially supported: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/452